# Issue with SAPUI5 SplitApp when emulated on mobile device using Google Chrome

Tags: sapui5

The splitApp loads master and detail pages on initial load on desktop and on tab as normal but when i try to emulate it on any phone like iphone 4,5,6 or nexus in chrome split app shows only master page on initial load instead of detail page.I tried all three modes of splitApp but does not work well with phone.

And also when i make my detail page to show nav button the default navigation button that comes with splitApp to switch to master from detail does not appear.

Regards,
Ajaay Krishna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That *is* the way a '**SplitApp**' behaves on a mobile device.

As there isn't enough screen space on a mobile device to display both the 'Master' and the 'Detail', as you can, say, on a desktop or a tablet, the expected behaviour on a mobile device is to first display the 'Master' list and then on navigation, display the 'Detail'. So there isn't anything wrong there.

As for the issue with the back navigation button, please post a code snippet to further elaborate..

Comment: Thanks for the reply and educating about splitapp.

Comment: then can u please tell how to switch between master and detail

Comment: Technically what ever code you have working on a desktop or tablet device should work..Just in case, you can find more information here -> https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SplitApp.html

Comment: I'm really sorry, but that isn't right. You can use the function oSplitApp.showMaster() if you want to let the master popup over the detail Page, but that only works in the Explorer. On Phone, nothing happened. (Tablet aren't tested yet)